# Opencv CV_FOURCC('F','L','V','1') not working?

Tags: opencv, flv, codec

I want to write `.flv` file from Opencv and spent so much time on it...
OpenCv 2.3 Documentation says we can create flv file with this codec

```
CV_FOURCC('F','L','V','1')
```

but I am always getting this **error**.

```
[flv @ 0x9bf5000] Tag FLV1/0x31564c46 incompatible with output codec id '22'
```

Please help....
Currently I am using **OpenCv 2.3** on **Ubuntu 10.10**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opencv can write flv format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970224/opencv-can-write-flv-format)

Comment: @karlphillip I am the one who has asked that question before...I didn't got it working....Please help me out....

Comment: I know you asked it :) But I don't have an answer for you. If you need more attention on that question, set a **bounty** on it.

Comment: did you install ffmpeg with "apt-get install ffmpeg"? I used to have a problem like this, then I removed it and I compiled from the source both ffmpeg (using the --enable-shared option) and x264 and recompiled opencv. It worked.

Comment: @SamFelix Thanks for your comment...I have installed and uninstalled ffmpeg, x264, OpenCv every version....Might be because I was reinstalling it....Please can you give me the link if you have one....

Comment: Sorry for taking so long. Here is the tutorial I have used to fix this problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095

Comment: @SamFelix Thanks for your reply...But I am still unable to get it working...Let you know that I am doing it for realtime output generated by OpenCv program...I dont need something which is their with ffmpeg...But I need something which can create FLV files with opencv-ffmpeg...Please Help...Please

Comment: Wazzzy, are you able to write in avi? have you compiled ffmpeg and x264 like I said? if you are able to write in avi, you can convert that later using system('ffmpeg ...')

Comment: @SamFelix You didnt got my problem....I want to convert flv file from opencv itself...I want it to stream it real time actually on rtmp stream....

Comment: I know, but opencv relies on ffmmpeg for doing that, that's why you should recompile it.

Comment: @SamFelix Thanks for your reply bro...But I had recompiled opencv for so many times..Now what I am trying is creating avi files from opencv and then by gstreamer trying to create rtmp stream...

Answer (score 7):

I know this is quite old, but I'll add my experience to this wall incase future people have this problem.

I encountered this using the PIM1 fourCC for output - my problem was solved when I changed from

```
video_output = cvCreateVideoWriter("disparity_output.mov", CV_FOURCC('P', 'I', 'M', '1'), 32, size, 0);
```

to:

```
video_output = cvCreateVideoWriter("disparity_output.mkv", CV_FOURCC('P', 'I', 'M', '1'), 32, size, 0);
```

changing the output path to have a file extension that was acceptable (or so I assume). Not sure if it helps, but it worked for me.

Comment: Anybody else hitting this, this fixed it for me. I was using `CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X')` and saving the file as `filename.mp4` and that would cause this issue to show up. Changed to `filename.avi` and the problem was resolved. Pretty silly if you ask me, it never would have occurred to me that it was being sensitive about the file extension, since it specifically asks what codec you want, but there you go.